# Forwarding a php array to twig template (Symfony)

Tags: php, arrays, symfony, templates, twig

I am trying to forward (render) my array from php to the twig template and than print everything out in the template.
My problem is to access the array in the twig template.

**Php array and render function:**

```
    while ( $row = mysqli_fetch_array ( $queryResult ) )
    {
        $tplArray = array (
                array (
                        'id' => $row ['id'] 
                ),
                array (
                        'name' => $row ['name'] 
                ) 
        );

        $tplArray = array (
                'id' => $row ['id'],
                'name' => $row ['name'] 
        );
    }

    return $this->render ( 'work/work.html.twig', array (
            'data' => $tplArray 
    ) );
```

**Trying to access the array in the twig template:**

```
    {% for entry in data %}
        {{ entry.id }}
        {{ entry.name }}
    {% endfor %}
```

This obviously do not work.
How can I get the data (id, name) from my $tplArray and print it out in the template?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `while` loop should look like this:

```
$tplArray = array(); 
while ( $row = mysqli_fetch_array ( $queryResult ) )
{
    $tplArray[] = array (
         'id' => $row ['id'],
         'name' => $row ['name'] 
    );
}
```

With this code, you assign an empty array (as a precaution) to `$tplArray` first. Then, using `[]` operator, you push a new element - an associative array with 'id' and 'name' attributes - at each step of `while` loop into this resulting array.

Currently, you reassign a *new* array as `$tplArray` value at each step of `while` instead.

Comment: Consider also renaming your first tplArray to something like $rows then have $tplArray = ['data' => $rows];  Using the same name for two completely different arrays makes things more confusing than they need to be.  Furthermore, $rows = mysqli_fetch_all($queryResult) will eliminate your first loop completely.